# How change order of SVD using numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, pca, svd

I am using Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) for Principal Component Analysis (PCA) of images.

I have 17 images of 20 X 20
so I created images matrix

```
M =  dim(400 X 17)
```

and when I apply SVD ( M = u @ d @ v) it gives me

```
u = dim(400 X 17)
d = dim(17 X 17)   
v = dim(17 X 17)
```

but I want to find `u = dim(400 X 400)` and `d =(400 X 400)` and `v =(400 X 17)` because there will 400 eigen vectors and 400 eigen values.

I even tried doing transpose but no luck

I know maybe question's title not much clear so please change as you like, and here are some info related to data

1. I centralized data by subtracting mean face
2. I tried to work around by finding eigenvectors of covariance matrix(MM') but when I tried to show PCA1 it only shows a black image

Please help me out

Comment: "400 eigen vectors and 400 eigen values" - for a matrix of rank 17? Nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eigenvalues aren't defined for rectangular matrices, but the singular values are related. As for eigenvectors, you always have a set of right and left eigenvectors that span column and row space.

[SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) is related to the eigenvalue decomposition of `MM'` and `M'M`

- `M'M = V (S'S) V'`
- `MM' = U (SS') U'`

now

- The columns of `V` are eigenvectors of `M'M`, which is of size `(17 x 17)` in your case. Therefore `V` is `(17 x 17)`
- The columns of `U` are eigenvectors of `MM'`, which is of size `(400 x 400)` in your case. Therefore `U` is `(400 x 400)`

Now what's the size of `S`? The non-zero elements of `S` (singular values) are the square roots of the non-zero eigenvalues of `M'M` and `MM'`. It can bew shown these two have the same sets of non-zero eigenvalues, therefore in the first case `S` is `(17 x 17)` and in the second case `(400 x 400)`. How do we reconcile this with the fact that our SVD is `M = USV'`? We build a [rectangular diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Rectangular_diagonal_matrices) `(400 x 17)` with the square roots of the 17 non-zero eigenvalues.

You can use SVD from `scipy`:

```
import scipy

u, s, vh = scipy.linalg.svd(M, full_matrices=True)
print(u.shape, s.shape, vh.shape)
```

that gives

```
((400, 400), (17,), (17, 17))
```

To get your `S` to `(400 x 17)`:

```
s = np.concatenate([np.diag(s), np.zeros((400-17, 17))], axis=0)
```

Check SVD correctness:

```
res = u@s@vh
np.allclose(res, a)

True
```

### Low rank matrix approximation

Sometimes you want to **approximate** your matrix `M` with a low-rank `M_tilde` of rank `r`, in this case, if you want to minimize the Frobenius norm between the two, you just keep the `r` largest singular values (Eckhart-Young theorem). 
The sizes of `U, S, V` become: `(400 x r), (r x r), (r x 17)`, where `S` is diagonal.

I don't know which function you're using, but this is what's happening: the zero singular values are being thrown away, as an `(m x n)` matrix can have at most rank `min(m, n)` (in your case 17).